# Can we define a variable having extern storage class associated with it?

Tags: c++, extern, storage-class-specifier

I was reading about extern storage class from this website:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/

and there is this example:

```
#include "somefile.h" 
extern int var; 
int main(void) 
{ 
 var = 10; 
 return 0; 
}
```

Supposing that somefile.h has the definition of var

Since we cannot define the variable which is an extern storage class how is it working correctly?

Does it mean that if an extern variable is already defined somewhere in the script and then if I re-define it any further in my code it's going to work?

Comment: `extern` means "this object exists somewhere", and as long as it is the case then all is fine. But a header containing variable definitions is considered broken, because merely including it into two separate TUs will violate ODR.

Comment: You should do the opposite: Define the variable in a source file, and declare (with `extern`) in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

C Language has methodology :- first Declare it and define it as you know daily use in C. You declare a function and define it somewhere downside.

The Main things is declaring a variable doesn't allocate memory. Memory is only allocated once you define it and in this case var is declare as well defined in somefile.h Memory is allocated via that file only and in this example extern states that this variable is defined somewhere else and Memory is already initialized for it.
[blog]: https://errbits.com/2021/12/16/storage-classes-in-c/ "Storage Classes in C"

And while compile time compiler verify that for same ,if var is already defined in somefile.h it will compile without error since it will check its symbol table to verify if it there.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `extern` means [**external linkage**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). The below given example gives some basics about `extern` usage.

#### someclass.h

```
#pragma once
extern int var; //this DECLARES an GLOBAL int variable named var with EXTERNAL LINKAGE
```

In the above `someclass.h`, we have **declared** a **global** `int` variable named `var` with **External linkage**. This means we will be able to use this variable from other files.

#### someclass.cpp

```
#include "somefile.h"
int var = 10; //this DEFINES the GLOBAL int variable named var that was DECLARED inside somefile.h with external linkage
```

In the above file `someclass.cpp` we have **defined** the **global** variable named `var` that was **declared** in file `somefile.h`.

#### main.cpp

```
#include "somefile.h" 
#include <iostream>
int main(void) 
{ 
 std::cout<< var<<std::endl;  //prints 10
 return 0; 
}
```

In the above file `main.cpp` we've **used**(printed on console) the **global** variable named `var` without defining it in `main.cpp`. This is possible because the variable `var` as i said has **external linkage**.

The output of the program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/X2h9bhESV).